# Laravel5 eager loading null value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

Eager loading won't work work if the field has `null` value. How do i escape the error

`Trying to get property of non-object`

and in model I set the relationship like this

```
public function bilstate()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Attribute', 'at_id', 'cu_bilstateid');
}
```

can someone share the experience? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `hasOne` relationship, if the related record exists, the relationship attribute will be set to an instance of the related model; if the related record does not exist, the relationship attribute will be set to null.

The eager loading is working fine, you just need to check if the related model exists before trying to access anything on it.

```
if ($model->bilstate) {
    echo 'bilstate exists: '.$model->bilstate->at_id;
} else {
    echo 'bilstate does not exist. Don't access attributes or you'll get an exception.';
}
```

Note: you can use the `is_null` method to check, if you'd like. However, using `isset` or `empty` is unreliable. If the relationship is not eager loaded, then the attribute will be lazy loaded using the `__get()` magic method. `is_null` will trigger this lazy load, whereas `isset` and `empty` will not.

Comment: your answer totally make sense for me as well, but what if we directly using `$model->bilstate->at_id` and its should not trigger error except replace with 'null'. Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: the reason is, they using short notation for relational data calling... if we can not call in that sense if relation doesn't exist, I don't think it's make sense. we need extra condition to filter across.